# DeepLink link from Action in Google Assistant when Android app is not present?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant

I read in the documentation that it's possible to open Android App using `DeepLink`:
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_helper.deeplink.html

```js
conv.ask(new DeepLink({
  destination: 'Google',
  url: 'example://gizmos',
  package: 'com.example.gizmos',
  reason: 'handle this for you',
}));
```

I wonder what happens if the user does not have target app installed on their phone?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen.

the app must be installed in the device, also it has to include an activity in the manifest file, with the suitable intent filter in order to detect the deeplink.

you can read more about [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Comment: Someone can invoke action on the device. In such case how I'm supposed to detect if the app is installed?